# Isosurface in matlab does not work

Tags: matlab, visualization

Hi I am trying to use the isosurface command together with patch:

```
l=Im{10};
l=l./max(l(:));
x=0:(size(l,1)-1);
y=0:(size(l,2)-1);
z=0:(size(l,3)-1);
[x y z]=meshgrid(y,x,z);
figure
p=patch(isosurface(x,y,z,l,1,'faceColor','b'));
```

so l has value's 1 and 0 and is not displaying the surface correctly at all. It just gives an empty white figure. l is the same size as the meshgrid If anyone could help me out that would be really awesome

Comment: As Nishant asks, what is Im?Because it seems thats the only think it can make this code not work!

Comment: `isosurface` doesn't work if the value you give it is the same as the maximum or minimum of your data.  You could use another value (0.5 etc).